# Good versioning practices when code can only run on a remote server

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, versioning

Good example of very bad practices here:

I'm currently dealing with a fast-growing (Java) code base and am struggling to define our versioning practices. To give you a little bit of background, our programs can only run on a remote server (which contains a massive amount of data that we cannot move anywhere else). As of now, we are all coding on our local machines and need to commit (we use git) every time we want to see an output, which is far from ideal. Are there any simple methods to avoid that?

Right now, we're also using only one branch which - I know - is a very bad practice when it comes to code base stability. The master branch is compiled locally (this is a large IntelliJ IDEA project with many files and dependencies), then the binaries are pushed to the server during commit. I'd like to move the compilation process to the server so we do not have to compile things locally. How would you handle that (I am especially worried about the dependencies)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You ask whether there is a way to "avoid" committing in order to see output. You are right that's far from ideal! But it's too hard to tell from your question what your options are. We'd need to know the nature of the "massive amount of data." How is it stored? Why can't it be moved? Why can't a subset of it be moved?

The answers to your other questions would -- in my view -- depend on your answer to that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The data is stored in flat binary files (this is much smaller). Are you suggesting we should move a small fraction of it to our local PCs so we can test the code before deploying it?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely what I am suggesting. You know the domain (I hope and assume) and the data. Once you take control of the data yourself -- for development purposes -- you can gain lots of benefits. You can test locally, as you point out. It also means you can write automated tests against a known dataset, for example -- if you know the data, you can know the results of any operation, and thus write an automated test which exercises the operation and verifies the results. So I would say setting up local data is the top priority -- it will set up other improvements.

Comment: Great insight, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to point out that using a single branch is not necessarily a bad thing:
 1. There are ways to block code from being merged into the remote master if it is going to "break" it
 2. For certain team setups a single branch can make coding faster and safer (by encouraging many small changes as an alternative to few big changes)

But moving on to your question about "building remotely".
You may use bamboo / jenkins / some other CI server to build your code on a remote agent (possibly your target machine) whenever code is pushed / merged.
To manage your builds (and specifically, to help with dependency management) I would recommend using maven / gradle (also, if it makes sense for your code base, you may want to "deploy" your maven artifacts onto a remote server)